# How to read and conver temperature sensor of MAX6633 with STM32

Tags: stm32, sensor, i2c, embedded, arm

I have a [MAX6633](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6633-MAX6635.pdf) on a board connected to a STM32 over I2C bus. This is a 12bit temp sensor and the datasheet says it stores the temperature in a 16 bit format (I think 2x8bit).

[image]

This is how I try to read the register. By the way, I do not do any write to the config register, is that OK?

```
  uint8_t temp[2] = {0xFF, 0xFF};
  HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c2, 0b1000000 << 1, 0x00, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, (uint8_t*)temp, 2, 1000);
  uint16_t result = (temp[0] << 8) | temp[1];
  printf("t1=%f\n", (float)result);
```

I get such a output:

```
t1=3152.000000
```

All the sensor address pins are tied to ground, hence the 0b1000000 as the address in the above code:

[image]

It is not a suprise that the number I get is wrong.

The picture above shows **each LSB is 0.0625 degrees C**. Does this mean I need to count number of "set" bits in the retuned value and multiply that by 0.0625?

Comment: **t1=3152.000000** result divided by 8 (to drop those 3 least-significant-bits), then multiplied by **0.0625** gives a result of 24.625 degrees C. That result seems to be in the right ballpark. However, putting a 2's complement number into a uint16_t variable, then casting to float, seems improper.

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks, yes the ambient temperature was definetly around 25 degrees C at that time.  Can you please elaborate   the 2's complement thing?

Comment: Your 'result' fails for negative temperature. Am no expert in C-types, but I'd suggest making 'result' a 16-bit signed integer 'int_16t'. Then perhaps the divide-by-8 can be done with 'result>>3' so that the sign bit is properly propagated using an arithmetic-shift-right. Then cast to float and multiply by 0.0625 to get temperature degrees C.

Comment: @glen_geek I believe that the behavior of a right shift is implementation-dependent for signed operands. It would be better to just divide by 8 and let the compiler simplify to a shift if that is possible.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Yes, I'd worry about portability - am guilty of second-guessing compilers in an effort to time-optimize. In any case, ensure that negative temperatures give a valid result. The divide-by-8 should be done as an int16_t, not as a float, to ensure those three LSB get dropped.